# LightAdmin - Customise parsing DateTime with app timezone

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-restcontroller, lightadmin

I am using LightAdmin 1.1.0.Snapshot with Spring Boot. I am using Joda DateTime to represent time with zone.

I can see LightAdmin captures date-time in UTC and Default Deserialization context used for parsing data is by UTC in LightAdmin. From debugging, I see LightAdmin uses its own ObjectMapper and MessageConverters using LightAdminRestMvcConfiguration, so it is not using the Spring Boot global overriders for customising the Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder like the one below.

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.timeZone(coreProperties.appTimeZone());
    return builder;
}
```

Any help on how to 1) override settings for Jackson in LightAdmin to parse with default app timezone or 2) Handle Json serialization / converter outside LightAdmin to solve this problem differently. Any help would be awesome.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I solved the problem is to reconfigure the LightAdmin beans after the context is loaded using the below.

```
@Component
public class AppContextListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>{

    @Inject
    CoreProperties coreProperties;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

        GenericWebApplicationContext appContext = getRootApplicationContext(event);
        WebApplicationContext lightAdminWebContext = getWebApplicationContext(appContext.getServletContext(), LightAdminWebApplicationInitializer.SERVLET_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
        lightAdminWebContext.getBeansOfType(ObjectMapper.class).values().stream()
                    .forEach(objectMapper -> objectMapper.setTimeZone(coreProperties.appTimeZone()));
    }

    private GenericWebApplicationContext getRootApplicationContext(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        return (GenericWebApplicationContext) (event.getApplicationContext().getParent() != null ? event.getApplicationContext().getParent() : event.getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```